# How do I argue against Duck-typing in a strongly typed language like Java?

Tags: java, duck-typing

I work on a team of Java programmers. One of my co-workers suggests from time-to-time that I do something like "just add a type field" (usu. "String type"). Or code will be committed laden with "`if (foo instanceof Foo){...} else if( foo instanceof Bar){...}`".

Josh Bloch's admonition that "tagged classes are a wan imitation of a proper class hierarchy" notwithstanding, what is my one-line response to this sort of thing? And then how do I elaborate the concept more seriously?

It's clear to me that - the context being Java - the type of Object under consideration is right in front of our collective faces - IOW: The word right after the "class", "enum" or "interface", etc.

But aside from the difficult-to-demonstrate or quantify (on the spot) "it makes your code more complicated", how do I say that "duck-typing in a (more or less) strongly-typed language is a stupid idea that suggests a much deeper design pathology?

Comment: That's not duck typing. Duck typing is just polymorphism in dynamic languages (implicit interfaces). What you speak of is just typechecking (which is bad even in duck-typed languages, like, say, Python).

Comment: @Devin Jeanpierre, @sharptooth, shouldn't somebody fix the question's title since we know that this is not duck typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "duck typing in strongly-typed languages" you actually mean "imitating (subtype) polymorphism in statically-typed languages".

It's not that bad when you have data objects (DTOs) that don't contain any behaviour. When you do have a full-blown OO model (ask yourself if this is really the case) then you should use the polymorphism offered by the language where appropriate.

Comment: bingo. that's what i was driving at. any thoughts about where invariants might play in? even data objects have rules on them. and if there are types of them, the rules would seem to be different.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, you said it reasonably well right there.

The truth is that the "instance of" comb is almost always a bad idea (the exception happening for example when you're marshaling or serializing, when for a short interval you may not have all the type information at hand.)  As josh says, that's a sign of a bad class hierarchy otherwise.

The way that you *know* it's a bad idea is that it makes the code brittle: if you use that, and the type hierarchy *changes*, then it probably breaks that instance-of comb everywhere it occurs.  What's more, you then lose the benefit of strong typing; the compiler can't help you by catching errors ahead of time.  (This is somewhat analogous to the problems caused by typecasts in C.)

#### Update

Let me extend this a bit, since from a comment it appears I wasn't quite clear.  The reason you use a typecast in C, or `instanceof`, it that you want to say "as if": use this `foo` as if it were a `bar`.  Now, in C, there is no run time type information around at all, so you're just working without a net: if you typecast something, the generated code is going to treat that address as if it contained a particular type no matter what, and you should only *hope* that it will cause a run-time error instead of silently corrupting something.

Duck typing just raises that to a norm; in a dynamic, weakly typed language like Ruby or Python or Smalltalk, everything is an untyped reference; you shoot messages at it at runtime and see what happens.  If it understands a particular message, it "walks like a duck" -- it handles it.

This can be very handy and useful, because it allows marvelous hacks like assigning a generator expression to a variable in Python, or a block to a variable in Smalltalk.  But it does mean you're vulnerable to errors at runtime that a strongly typed language can catch at compile time.

In a strongly-typed language like Java, you can't really, strictly, have duck typing at all: you *must* tell the compiler what type you're going to treat something as.  You can get something like duck typing by using type casts, so that you can do something like

```
Object x;   // A reference to an Object, analogous to a void * in C

// Some code that assigns something to x

((FoodDispenser)x).dropPellet();          // [1]

// Some more code

((MissleController)x).launchAt("Moon");   // [2]
```

Now at run time, you're fine as long as x is a kind of `FoodDispenser` at [1] or `MissleController` at [2]; otherwise *boom*.  Or unexpectedly, no *boom*.

In your description, you protect yourself by using a comb of `else if` and `instanceof`

```
 Object x ;

 // code code code 

 if(x instanceof FoodDispenser)
      ((FoodDispenser)x).dropPellet();
 else if (x instanceof MissleController )
      ((MissleController)x).launchAt("Moon");
 else if ( /* something else...*/ ) // ...
 else  // error
```

Now, you're protected against the run-time error, but you've got the responsibility of doing something sensible later, at the `else`.

But now imagine you make a change to the code, so that 'x' can take the types 'FloorWax' and 'DessertTopping'.  You now must go through all the code and find all the instances of that comb and modify them.  Now the code is "brittle" -- changes in the requirements mean lots of code changes.  In OO, you're striving to make the code less brittle.

The OO solution is to use polymorphism instead, which you can think of as a kind of limited duck typing: you're defining all the operations that something can be trusted to perform.  You do this by defining a superior class, probably abstract, that has all the methods of the inferior classes.  In Java, a class like that is best expressed an "interface", but it has all the type properties of a class.  In fact, you can see an interface as being a promise that a particular class can be trusted to act "as if" it were another class.

```
  public interface VeebleFeetzer { /* ... */ };
  public class FoodDispenser implements VeebleFeetzer { /* ... */ }
  public class MissleController implements VeebleFeetzer { /* ... */ }
  public class FloorWax implements VeebleFeetzer { /* ... */ }
  public class DessertTopping implements VeebleFeetzer { /* ... */ }
```

All you have to do now is use a reference to a VeebleFeetzer, and the *compiler* figures it out for you.  If you happen to add another class that's a subtype of VeebleFeetzer, the compiler will select the method and check the arguments in the bargain

```
VeebleFeetzer x;   // A reference to anything 
                   // that implements VeebleFeetzer

// Some code that assigns something to x

x.dropPellet();

// Some more code

x.launchAt("Moon");
```

Comment: Well instanceof makes the cast safe, unlike C, so you don't really lose the compilers help in that case.  Doesn't make it any less of a bad way to do it though!

Comment: The other issue is that adding the FloorWax class forces you to visit a whole load of methods, unrelated to FloorWax, and add "if (x instanceof FloorWax)" into the switch.

Comment: It seems you use strong typed as being the same thing as static typed. This is not unusal but a more common use is that Strongly typed types are checked at runtime. s="Year: "+2009 # TypeError 
Weakly typed is like C, you are on your own. This has nothing to do with static or dynamic typing.
 
* Java, static and strong typed.
* Ruby & Pyton, dynamic and strong typed.
* C, static and weak typed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages#Type_systems

Answer (score 6):

This isn't so much duck typing as it is just proper object-oriented style; indeed, being able to subclass class A and call the same method on class B and have it do something else is the entire point of inheritance in languages.

If you're constantly checking the type of an object, then you're either being too clever (though I suppose it's this cleverness that duck typing aficionados enjoy, except in a less brittle form) or you're not embracing the basics of object-oriented programming.

Comment: Then use duck typing the right way, passing Object*'s.  Using RTTI makes the code *less* object-oriented, to the extent that it defeats locality and makes the code brittle.

Comment: Did I say something that contradicts this?

Comment: Love Wikipedia's RTTI article: "In the original C++ design, Stroustrup did not include run-time type information, because he thought this mechanism was frequently misused [1]."

Answer (score 3):

hmmm...

correct me if I am wrong but tagged classes and duck-typing are two different concepts though not necessarely mutally exclusive.

When one has the urge of using tags in a class to define the type then one should, IMHO, revise their class hiearchy as it is a clear sing of conceptual bleed where an abstract class needs to know the the implementation details that the class parenthood tries to hide.  Are you using the correct pattern ?  In other words are you trying to coerce behaviour in a pattern that does not naturally support it ?

Where as duck-typing is the ability to loosely define a type where a method can accept any types just so long as the necessary methods in the parameter instance are defined.  The method will then use the parameter and call the necessary methods without too much bother on the parenthood of the instance.

So here... the smelly hint is, as Charlie pointed out, the use of instanceof.  Much like static or other smelly keywords, whenever they appear one must ask "Am I doing the right thing here ?", not that they are inhertitly wrong but they are oftenly used to hack through a bad or ill fitted OO desing.

Answer (score 2):

My one line response would be that you lose one of the main benefits of OOP: polymorphism.  This reduces the time to develop new code (developers love to develop new code, so that should help your argument :-)

If, when adding a new type to an existing system, you have to add logic, aside from figuring out which instance to construct, then, in Java, you are doing something wrong (assuming that the new class should simply be a drop in replacement for another).

Generally, the appropriate way to handle this in Java is to keep the code polymorphic and make use of interfaces.  So anytime they find themselves wanting to add another variable or do an instanceof they should probably be implementing an interface instead.

If you can convince them to change the code it is pretty easy to retrofit interfaces into the existing code base.  For that matter, I'd take the time to take a piece of code with instanceof and refactor it to be polymorphic.  It is much easier for people to see the point if they can see the before and after versions and compare them.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to point your co-worker to the Liskov substitution principle, one of the five pillars in SOLID.

Links:

- [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)
- [Article written by Uncle Bob](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm generally a fan of duck-typed languages like python, I can see your problem with it in java.

If you are writing all the classes that will ever be used with this code, then you don't need to duck-type, because you don't need to allow for cases where code can't directly inherit from (or implement) an interface or other unifying abstraction.

A downside of duck-typing is that you have an extra class of unit tests to run on your code: a new class could return a different type than expected, and subsequently cause the rest of the code to fail. So although duck-typing allows backward-flexibility, it requires a lot of forward thinking for tests.

In short you have a catch-all (hard) instead of a catch-few (easy). I think that's the pathology.

Answer (score 1):

Why "imitate a class hierarchy" instead of designing and using it? One of the refactoring methods is replacing "switch"es (chained ifs are almost the same) with polymorphism. Why use switches where polymorphism would lead to cleaner code?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't duck typing, it is just a bad way to simulate polymorphism in a language that has (more or less) real polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Two arguments to answer the titled question:

1) Java is supposed to be "write once, run anywhere," so code that was written for one hierarchy shouldn't throw RuntimeExceptions when we change the environment somewhere.  (Of course, there are exceptions -- pun -- to this rule.)

2) The Java JIT performs very aggressive optimizations that rely on knowing that a given symbol must be of one type and one type only.  The only way to work around this is to cast.

As others have mentioned, your "instance of" doesn't match with the question I've answered here.  Anything with any types, duck or static, may have the issue you described.  There are better OOP ways to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instanceof you can use the Method- and the Strategy-Pattern, mixed together the code looks much better than before...