# Arguments for duck-typing in a strongly-typed OOP language?

Tags: oop, strong-typing, duck-typing

Is there a case where you wrote something in such a language (e.g. C#, Java), and missed duck typing? (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700113/how-do-i-argue-against-duck-typing-in-a-strongly-typed-language-like-java) for arguments against duck typing)

Comment: I assume you mean statically-typed rather than strongly-typed?

Comment: Kylotan, no, that would be contradictory.  dynamic <-> static, strong <-> weak are orthogonal.

Comment: I know, that's the point I was making: the question's wording implies that strongly-typed languages do not have duck typing. Some of them do, ie. Python.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you need to work with code that you do not own, and that does not have proper abstraction (HttpContext anyone?). As you can't have a method of yours accept IHttpContext, since HttpContext type does not have that kind of abstraction, you have to settle for an Adapter and/or Factory and such.
Would have been extremely nicer if you could have defined the IHttpContext contract in your code, make it look like the HttpContext, set your method to accept IHttpContext, and have a true, real HttpContext object passed in to duck into IHttpContext.

Comment: First answer of yours I see :)

Comment: you should be looking harder :)

Answer (score 2):

That other question had little to do with duck typing. Anyway, assuming this doesn't get closed I'd say the one time I really miss duck typing is when trying to test classes with big API's. We need a separate framework to create mocks of them while in another programming language you could conceivably just pass in a self written class that implements the bare basics of what you need.

For instance, try to mock a JDBC ResultSet in java without a framework, it's a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 2):

Never.  Been using Java since the '90's and Python since '01 or so.

Here's why I never missed duck typing in Java.

The "Duck Typing in Java Question" is really about an absolute failure to understand Polymorphism.  If you ever think you need any kind of run-time type identification or "isinstance" functionality, you've failed to grasp Polymorphism and you're doing it wrong.

See the [Programmer Ignorance Pet Peeve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve) question.  Failure to grasp polymorphism is a huge problem and leads to this "duck typing in Java" mistake.

If you understand polymorphism, you don't need duck typing and you don't miss it when switching between Python and Java.

On a related note, I only use Python's `isinstance()` as part of an assertion to make a function that requires integers blow up when it gets a non-integer.  `isinstance()` is sometimes used with attempts in Java to do duck-typing-like things.

The point is that I'm old (52) and not very smart.  So I have to keep to a "strong-ish" class hierarchy in Python or I get confused.  I always left a space in a Python design for refactoring into more strict class hierarchy if it become necessary.

Comment: Using isinstance is not duck typing, in fact it subverts duck typing.

class A { method foo() { ... } }
class B { method foo() { ... } }

function not_duck_typed(x) { if( x isinstance A ) { x.foo() } }

function duck_typed(x) { x.foo() }

The who point of duck typing is you can pass an instance of either A or B into duck_typed, despite the fact that they don't share a common anecestor or formal interface. Duck typing is still polymorphism.

Comment: You're confusing run-time type identification/isinstance with duck typing. In Java, interfaces are defined explicitly - in duck typed languages they're defined implcitly by the methods an object exposes.

Answer (score 0):

Having a language perform duck-typing based upon method signatures should never be necessary outside situations where a language is trying to work around a design weakness (as was the case with C# `foreach` construct).  On the other hand, there are many situations where it would be helpful to do something similar to duck-typing with interfaces.  For example, if one has a method `UseDuck` which takes a generic parameter that's constrained to implement interfaces `IWalkLikeDuck` and `IQuackLikeDuck`, code which has an variable of a generic type which is constrained to implement both `IWalkLikeDuck` and `IQuackLikeDuck` can pass it to `UseDuck`.  There is no nice way, however, for the code to persist it in a form which can be passed to `Wowzo` once it exits.  It would be very helpful if one could define a duck-typed `IWalkAndTalkLikeDuck` which inherited from both of the other interfaces, but *would automatically be regarded as implemented by any class which implements both `IWalklikeDuck` and `ITalkLikeDuck`*, such that one could store a reference to any type which was know to implement `IWalkLikeDuck` and `ITalkLikeDuck` into a `List<IWalkAndTalkLikeDuck>`.